# PHP ZipArchive ExtractTo Hanging Issue

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to unzip one file that has two csv files in it. Every variation of my code has the same results. Using the code I have currently, it gets only one file partially out and then hangs. The file unzipped shows that it is 38,480kb and gets stuck toward the end of row 214410. The true file in the archive is 38,487kb and has a total of 214442 rows. Any idea what could be causing this to hang at the last minute? I am doing all my testing with xampp on localhost on a windows 7 machine. This is in php, and is the only code in the file. The required zip file is in the same folder with it.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('ItemExport.zip') === TRUE) {
for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $zip->extractTo('.', array($filename));
    }                   
$zip->close();
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT**
The file shows up almost immediately in the correct directory and a few seconds later it gives the file size 38,480kb. At that point it doesn't do anything else. After waiting on it for MORE than long enough 5-10 minutes+ I opened the file. It is "locked for editing by 'another user'" as it is still being held by http. The writing to the csv file just stops mid-word, mid-sentence on column 9 of 11 in row 214,442.

Comment: Are you tried setting max_execution_time limit to 0 or other value, like 3600?

Comment: I tested both 0 and 3600 and the file still hangs at 38,480kb.